# Selector or ComboBox does not display all JSON in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, json, select, combobox, sapui5

I have a JSON of countries and what I want is to show them in a combobox or selector all the attributes of the json but it only shows me 99, it is as if it was dividing the array, is there any way to solve this? my json has about 200 attributes. This is a small part of the json:

```
{
  "countries": [
    {
      "name_en": "Afghanistan",
      "name_es": "Afganistán",
      "nationality_en": "Afghan",
      "nationality_es": "Afgano/a",
      "dial_code": "+93",
      "code": "af"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Albania",
      "name_es": "Albania",
      "nationality_en": "Albanian",
      "nationality_es": "Albano/a",
      "dial_code": "+355",
      "code": "al"
    },
    {
      "name_en": "Algeria",
      "name_es": "Argelia",
      "nationality_en": "Algerian",
      "nationality_es": "Argelino/a",
      "dial_code": "+213",
      "code": "dz"
    }
]}
```

this is the view:

```
<Label class="label" text="{i18n>Nationality}" required="true"/>
<ComboBox id="comboNationality" placeholder="{i18n>Nationality}" class="input" width="100%" required="true" tooltip="{i18n>SelectNationality}" items="{ path: 'country>/Dato' }">
    <core:ListItem key="{country>code}" text="{country>nationality}"/>
</ComboBox>
```

any idea why it cuts the json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONModel has a default size of 100 elements. You can use [setSizeLimit](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.62.0/#/api/sap.ui.model.Model/methods/setSizeLimit) method to change this behavior

Comment: Thank you so much. I just found another solution, with this `items="{ path: 'country>/Dato', length: '300' }"` in the view you can determinate the size too. Thank you

Comment: I usually prefer leveraging the setSizeLimit method because you can pass the extact size of your model runtime :-)